# JQuery: подсчитать сколько элементов на странице

Tags: jquery, input

На странице есть кнопка по клику добавляю input#field, необходимо ограничить количество input#field на странице

Добавляю input так

```
$("#click-field").on("click", function() {

    $(this).before('<input id="field" name="field" type="text">');
});
```

Нужно сделать ограничение на +2 #field. Пробовал так

```
$("#click-field").on("click", function() {

    var count = $("#field").length;

    if(count > 2) return false;

    $(this).before('<input id="field" name="field" type="text">');
});
```

Не получилось, видит только 1 #field

Comment: "id должен быть уникальным" - в рамочку и рядом с монитором поставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проще всего так

```
$("#click-field").on("click", function() {
    if ($('input.input-class', $(this).parent()).length >= 2) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).before('<input name="field" type="text" class="input-class">');
});
```

Comment: Не подойдет, если в случае удаления input со странице потом вновь его не добавить. Можно конечно попробовать после удаления делать -1 в count, но может кто подскажет более интересно решение?

Comment: в вопросе не было сказано, что инпуты могут быть удалены.

изменил код.